# Paginate records?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, records

I'm creating a custom plugin for customer reviews on products. 
In the CP I have an interface to view and aprove these. What I am wondering is if it is any easy way to paginate my records? Right now on my index page Im just calling a twig extension that does a DB query for all rows in a review table. When this table gets bigger I might have performance and UX issues listing all the comments in one go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `paginate`. In my installation, I paginate through blog articles:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('articles').limit(4) as pageInfo, articles %}
```

Then, you can just access them as usual:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am looking to paginate my custom records, so I cant use craft.entreis to fetch my own objects.